# GuitarPro: Change to Eb, but keep notation in E

Tags: tuning, instruments, key

I just downloaded GuitarPro 7.5.  I used to use GuitarPro quite a bit, but it's been a while.

I like to tune down and play in Eb.  I want to change a song to sound 1/2 step lower, but want to keep the notation and tab in original finger and original key.

Ie->Smoke on the Water in standard E tuning.

I want the key signature to remain the same (Bb major, for Smoke on the Water), or say I load a song that is in C. Drop the pitch to B, but I want the tab/score to remain in C.  Hope that makes sense

-> change pitch to E flat, but keep notation/tab as was originally

I read "real" music much better than I read tab, so I don't want to hide the score.

Hope that makes sense.  I used to do this all the time, but am having worst time trying to remember how I did this.

-->> It's easy to do in GuitarPro 6, but not GuitarPro 7.  Not sure why.

EDIT:

Here are a couple of screencaps.  First is a Steve Morse tune in A minor, w/ key in notation being C.  When I change the tuning to Eb it also changes the score so that there are accidentals. I've tried transposing 1/2 step, but this doesn't work. There has to be a way to manipulate the score w/o altering the pitch/tone that is played.

First pic:
[image]

And here is 2nd pic:

[image]

I want the musical notation to look like this but played w/ Eb tuning. This is score w/o the tab:

[image]

Hope that makes sense.  I want to be able to drop tone/pitch 1/2 step, but be able to keep the notation in original key.  I can't seem to manipulate the score w/o changing the actual pitch.  Hope that makes sense.

ps.  If you're wondering why?  I'm using an Ibanez w/ locking tuners.  It's tuned to Eb

Comment: Can you load your Guitar Pro file in TuxGuitar and see if you can transpose the file there? PS I like 1/2 step down and you can switch to standard fast with CAPO 1. TuxGuitar also shows the scales if you like to find chords etc. I like that software. Do all the notes show up sharped when you change the key. Example are the lower and higher octaves also sharped/or flattened I noticed a lot of sheet music will not show these expect for the sharps next to the staff.

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate of a more recent Q&A. The newer post is more general, has the identical answer, and the answer is accepted.

Answer (score 4):

You simply have to change the tuning for each instrument track in the "Track Inspector".

Hope this helps.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

File -> Sheetstyle.

Ensure "Capo and shifted tunings impact standard notation" is unchecked. Then verify the key signature is correct.

That should fix it.

Note: I've been searching for years also, finally found it!

Answer (score 0):

Now I don't know GuitarPro at all, so my answer is totally based on the pictures you supplied.

Take the last picture where you have written how you want it to look without the tab.

On the right side there are some options.

There is this option:
"Transposition tonality"
C played as C

Wouldn't all you need to do be to change that to:
C played as B
?

Comment: I tried that.  No go.  It brings the tonality down 1/2 step, necessitating all the accidentals.  It's easy to do in GuitarPro6. I suppose I'll do that sort of editing in GuitarPro6.  I'm liking 6 better than 7 so far.  If I wanted to just have a printout, "read-only" transcript I could just write it as usual, and play as usual w/ the Eb tuning.  But, to get sound I have to choose either play in E standard tuning, or have the mess to read.