# Guitar Pro 7.5 - add capo but keep notation

Tags: guitar-pro

When specifying a Capo is it standard to have the notation change to the actual pitch? My understanding is that the addition of the capo should not change the notation

When I add a capo in Guitar Pro 7.5 the notation changes. Here is an example:

Before Capo:

[image]

After Capo at Fret 1:

The E in the notation has become an F

[image]

How do you prevent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this via `File -> Stylesheet -> Systems and Staves` and uncheck `Capo and shifted tunings impact standard notation` (thanks to [this answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/92887/80371))

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It has to change as *the tab* is the same: by adding a capo at fret 1 and if you do the same fingerings than before, effectively all your notes will be transposed a semi-tone higher.

If you want the standard notation to stay the same you could transpose that part in GP (here, a semi tone down for instance).

Comment: `you could transpose that part in GP` <-- care to share an example?